# problem installing ubuntu 12.04 after downloading

Tags: installation

i have downloaded ubuntu 12.04 and the flle is in my hard drive as ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.dap    but while installing ubuntu it opens with KM player and get hanged.i have checked the proper ties of the file and got - type of file:dap file and open with KM player.Please help me out.....

Comment: The downloaded Ubuntu install image file should be `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso`. The filetype `.dap` is **not** correct. My *guess* based on a quick Google search is that this is an incomplete download file. (Did try downloading using a download manager program named Download Accelerator Plus?) Get a complete download of the file and then verify the checksum of the file to ensure it was downloaded correctly.

Comment: You can find the MD5 checksum for the ISO you download here: [**UbuntuHashes**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes). Instructions for how to check the ISO image against the MD5 checksum are here: [**HowToMD5SUM**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).

Answer (score 2):

`dap` is a partial download.  When it's complete it will be `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso`.  Then it *should* work properly.

It's from a proprietary download accelerator file extension -- much like the common something.part file you get from a web browser.